# excel vba compare 2 columns and list non matching results

Tags: excel, vba

I try to compare two columns and get the non-matching results listed somewhere else.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
Sub match_columns()
Dim i, Lastrow1, Lastrow3 As Integer
Dim found As Range

With Worksheets("sht1")

Lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastrow1

answer1 = .Range("A" & i).Value
Set found = Sheets("sht2").Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer1)

    If found Is Nothing Then
        Set rngNM = .Range("A" & i.Row)
    Else
        Set rngNM = Union(rngNM, .Range("A" & i.Row))
    End If
Next i


End With

    If Not rngNM Is Nothing Then rngNM.Copy Worksheets("sht3").[A2]

    Worksheets("sht3").[A1] = "title"

    Lastrow3 = Sheets("sht3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("sht3").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow3).Copy



End Sub
```

I currently get an "Runtime error 424; Object required" for the following:
Set rngNM = .Range("A" & i.Row)

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: maybe `Set rngNM = .Range("A" & i`)?

Comment: It's wrong because `i` is an integer and that does not have a `row` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Compare_Two_Columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, out As Worksheet, c As Range, i As Long, m As Long, k As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set out = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        m = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim a(1 To m)

        For i = 1 To m
            Set c = sh.Range("A:A").Find(What:=ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If c Is Nothing Then k = k + 1: a(k) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next I

        If k > 0 Then
            With out
                .Range("A1").Value = "Title"
                .Range("A2").Resize(k).Value = Application.Transpose(a)
            End With
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there also a way to add an extra if .. then to this code?
For instance: if text "ABC" is found in sh.Range("AR:AR") for the range k than list, else don't list?

Comment: Maybe adding extra condition using `AND` in this part `If c Is Nothing Then`.